# Add Query Hint inside of JPA Specification

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, query-hints

I'm looking for a way to add a QueryHint inside of a Specifications `toPredicate` method. As I'm only having access to `Root<T>`, `CriteriaQuery<?>` and `CriteriaBuilder` instances I'm wondering if this is even possible.

I'm also okay with setting a global default, so that the hint is applied to all queries globally, but I would prefer to somewhat add it inside of the Specification. Maybe hibernate has a property I didn't spot in it's hibernate.properties file to achieve that.

I know I could achieve that by overriding the `JpaSpecificationExecutors` corresponding method and annotate the method with `@QueryHints`, but as I would have to do that for all Repositories, I would prefer to not do that as it is somewhat error prone.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible but you have to apply Criteria API directly without Spring Data wrappers. Here is an example from [Vlad Mihalcea's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1025118/vlad-mihalcea) [article](https://vladmihalcea.com/optimize-jpql-criteria-api-query-plans-hibernate-statistics/).

```java
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
 
CriteriaQuery<Post> criteria = builder.createQuery(Post.class);
Root<Post> fromPost = criteria.from(Post.class);
 
criteria.where(
    builder.in(
        fromPost.get("id")).value(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)
    )
);
 
List<Post> posts = entityManager
    .createQuery(criteria)
    .setHint("hint_name", "hint_value")
    .getResultList();
```

If you do want to stick to Spring Data Specification, you can try to use `@QueryHints` annotation.

```java
public interface RobotRepositoryRobot extends JpaRepository<Robot, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Robot> {
    @Override
    @QueryHints(
        @QueryHint(name = "hint_name", value = "hint_value")
    )
    List<Robot> findAll(Specification<Robot> spec);
}
```

Though in this case, hints aren't dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this discussion is a bit old but i had a similar issue, where i created a spefication for a findAll query. Within this specification it was not possible for me to add a query Hint. Therefore I added an base Repository where i could override the findAll method and add a query hint.
how to create the base Repo is described here:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-method-in-all-repositories

for the queryHint:

```
    TypedQuery<T> query = this.getQuery(specification, pageable);
    ((CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter<?>) query).addQueryHint(your hint)
```

Sometimes it is possible to add a Custom SQL Dialect that this is working, but that depends on the DB you are using.